# Shifted Java Date is in the past

Tags: java, date, time, shift

I have a problem I can't uderstand - if I add more than 24 days, the shifted date in the past.

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
long shift = 3600000 * 24 * 24;
System.out.println(new Date(start));
System.out.println(new Date(start + shift));
```

For 24 day shift:

```
start - Wed Apr 18 11:37:12 CEST 2012
end - Sat May 12 11:37:12 CEST 2012
```

For 25 day shift:

```
start - Wed Apr 18 11:37:55 CEST 2012
end - Sat Mar 24 17:35:08 CET 2012
```

Could someone advise me why it behaves this way? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're doing Integer multiplication, and then transforming the result into a long. The multiplication overflows, so the result is negative.

Use the following code to do long multiplication:

```
long shift = 3600000L * 24 * 24;
```

Comment: Oops, my fault, I have not seen this even after several times checking. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'd really advise against solving your problem this way; use java.util.Calendar instead. It's more likely to cope with corner-cases like daylight saving changes, plus the API is nicer.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(new Date(start));
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 24)
Date shifted = cal.getTime();
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should just use java.util.Calendar as below:

```
Calendar c = GregorianCalendar.getInstance(); //time default to now
c.add(Calendar.DATE, 24); //adds 24 days
Date end = c.getTime();
```